# Problems when moving QGIS files between computers

Tags: qgis

I have tried uploading QGIS files together with the CSV and shp files behind all layers to another computer (via usb) for others to continue working on it. Now when we open the same file and update the data source the layer cannot be edited and just have a gray table image on the side. When clicking on the layers it is impossible to add for example symbols.

Does anybody know how to move QGIS files between computers and continue working on the same file without the layers becoming unworkable?

Comment: If it's a csv-based layer: csv can not be edited in QGIS

Comment: You can use the QPackage plugin to move the project and all its layers to a single folder and then put that on a network drive.  The plugin currently doesn't update the source paths to the new folder's files, oddly, but you can use the change Data Source plugin to do that.  This preserves symbology, layer names, etc. but you may need to update the definition query.  A manual alternative is to just copy the datasets to a folder, add the project file, and then use the change Data Source plugin to update paths.  Then move the folder where you want.

Comment: Thank you for the comment Johns! But that is exactly what I have done. I made a folder with all files. Moved that between computers, open the file, and updated the data source. After I did that the layers could not be "used" in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend exporting all files/layers to one GeoPackage. You can also save your QGIS Project file to that very same GeoPackage. Make sure you set your project paths to "relative" (Project->Properties->General->Save Paths)

This will ensure hassle-free copying from one computer to another!

Comment: Nice! Will try to do this then. Thank you!